# comparing strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am comparing two strings that supposed to be equal.
From some reason it thinks they are not.

this is the code:

```
   function(){
    prev = $('h').value;
    now = $('content').innerHTML;
    alert(prev);
    alert(now);
    if(prev == now)
    {
    $('content').fade({ duration: 3.0, from: 0, to: 1 });
    }
    else{alert('lol');}
    }
```

I made added the alert functions to be sure they are equal.

Any idea why it gives me the "alert('lol)" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings are probably different, but it's hard to see leading and trailing whitespace in `alert()` boxes. You can try to [trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) the strings:

```
if ($.trim(prev) == $.trim(now)) {
    $('content').fade({ duration: 3.0, from: 0, to: 1 });
}
```

Comment: I am using Prototype not jQuery. Do you know the alternative of trim() in Prototype?

Comment: @Oded, sorry, missed the tag. `trim()` is called [strip()](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string#method-strip) in Prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect:

You need to use `val()` instead of `value` with jQuery selector or convert it to DOM element with `get` or `[0]` shorthand to use `value`.

`value` gives you what is inside `value` attribute while `innerHTML` gives you the inner html of an element. You should either use `value` for both elements or `innerHTML` depending on the type of elements :)

**Example:**

```
prev = $('h').val();
now = $('content').val();

if(prev == now)
```

Or:

```
prev = $('h')[0].innerHTML;
now = $('content')[0].innerHTML;

if(prev == now)
```

Comment: I know. And because of that the value in $('h') is:"<h2>check</h2>"

Answer (score 1):

Two strings may look the same in an alert box but not be the same. For example, spaces at the beginning or end of one of the strings.

I find if I have this problem, I can spot it more easily by adding markers to the string when I alert it, like so:

```
alert('['+mystring+']');
```

Also, `console.log()` is a more powerful way to debug this sort of thing than `alert()`. `console.log()` is available in most modern browsers when using their built-in developer tools (in Firefox, you need to install the Firebug plugin for this).

If you find you have leading/trailing spaces to get rid of, you can do so very easily with a quick regex:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/((^\s)|(\s$))/,'');
```

This will remove all white-space from the beginning and end of the string.

Hope that helps.